# Vietnamese in TexShop -- MacTex

Tags: fonts, texshop, mactex

I am new in using MacTex and I use TexShop to compile LaTEX documents. I have many files in Vietnamese when I use Winshell (with MikTex) in Windows, and I transfer it to my MacBook. When I typerest the file, it run fine and the PDF export file show correctly. But in TexShop the Vietnamese for go wrong, It turn into something strange fonts. How should I do to let my old file with Vietnamese font from Winshell, appear correctly as in TexShop, in Macbook?

In Options tab of Winshell: Font: Times New Roman, Script: Vietnamese, Encoding: UTF-8

Sorry for my English, and MacTex, TeXShop are new for me.

Comment: Most probably a problem of text encoding. Which encoding did you use with Winshell? Also, it would be nice to produce a minimal (but complete) example of coding reproducing the problem.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. In Options tab of Winshell: Font: Times New Roman, Script: Vietnamese, Encoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, I deduce that TeXShop is not yet configured to UTF-8 text encoding. To do that, open the Preferences of TeXShop, select the “Document” panel (the first panel starting from the left), and select `Unicode (UTF-8)` in the `Encoding` section, like here (French version of TeXShop, but it should look close in other languages):

[image]

After this change, it could be necessary to quit and restart TeXShop to activate it.

If you want to do that on a per-file basis, insert this magic comment at the beginning of your `.tex` files:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

Comment: Haa, I solve it follows the above suggestion and set font Time New Roman. Thank you fpast!

Comment: @ Hà Duy Hưng Hưng vote cho tác giả trả lời bằng cách bấm vào nút đầu ngòi bút phía trên nhé.